# How to select images that are not associated to a link

Tags: xpath

I need to select all the images in a page that are not associated with a link.

Basically, this is the list of all the images I'm interested in:

```
//div[contains(@id,'product-desc')]//img
```

and I need to remove this selection from the one above:

```
//div[contains(@id,'product-desc')]//a[@href]//img
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: `//div[contains(@id,'product-desc')]//img[not(ancestor::a)]` should do the job

Answer (score 0):

You should try to negate like this:

```css
//a[not(@href)]
```